# How to avoid apache2 revealing hidden directory and/or file structure

Tags: security, apache-2.2

When someone fetches a *denied* URL that exists, he gets:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin/admin.php on this server.
Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.9 with Suhosin-Patch Server
```

When someone goes to a URL that *does not exist* he will get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /notexisting/notthere.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.9 with Suhosin-Patch Server
```

This way someone can find out information about the directory structure in an area, that is actually not open to the public. Is this true?

If I were paranoid, what could I do? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use SetEnvIf to check for something, like whether Remote_Addr is internal or not, and then use mod_rewrite to give 404's based on the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Note this doesn't necessarily tell them that `/admin/admin.php` exists. If `/admin` were forbidden, `/admin/notthere.php` would also be a `403 Forbidden`. So it's not explicitly giving away any information about your directory structure.

If you are paranoid, you could create a subdomain where the root is protected. That way, for an unauthorized user, *any url will result in a `403 Forbidden` message*

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the way Apache reacts to error, for example by setting an ErrorDocument for each error:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: but this would not change the http result code? an attacker could still look for it?